# How to determine a cell is merged with another cell in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a function for following sheet which will give me output in the below
mentioned manner.

[image]

```
Logger.log(getMergedRange("B2"));
Logger.log(getMergedRange("C6"));
Logger.log(getMergedRange("C2"));
Logger.log(getMergedRange("D7"));

function getMergedRange(var currentCell){
    ...........
    ...........
    return mergedRange;
}
```

The output should be:
**A1:C3

C6:D7

A1:C3

C6:D7**

Comment: Looks like this has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025543/how-do-i-know-if-spreadsheet-cells-are-merged-using-google-apps-script

Comment: No this is not what I am looking for. The accepted answer there wont work for me if the spreadsheet has a huge data. one more answer by the same author works for only active range and it does not return the r1c1 notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getMergedRanges() with a range containing a single cell and it should return an array containing just one merged range if the cell is part of a merged range.