# Get the value of a cell in a merged range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm iterating over a column in a sheet, which contains merged cells spread over a few rows. E.g.

```
        |-----
 row 1  |  5
        |-----
 row 2  |
 row 3  |  3
 row 4  |
        |-----
 row 5  |
        |-----
 row 6  |  1
        |-----
```

I use merging here to show a single value shared by multiple cells.

The problem is that when I'm trying to collect the data and I'm using `Range.getValues()` only the first cell in the merged range has a non-empty value (in the example `['5','3','','','','','1']`), so I can't know which cells are actually empty and which ones belong to a merged range.

The only workaround I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=618) was color everything and look at the color of the cells (but this is super ugly).

Any nice way so solve this problem?

Comment: This was already answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025543/how-do-i-know-if-spreadsheet-cells-are-merged-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also possible workaround is to set and then get horizontal allignment.

This code:

```
function GetMyRange() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1:A6");
      range1.setHorizontalAlignment("right");
      var vals = range1.getValues();
      var alignment = range1.getHorizontalAlignments();


      Logger.log(vals);
      Logger.log(alignment);
    }
```

gives the result:

```
[[5.0], [3.0], [], [], [], [1.0]]

[[right], [right], [general], [general], [right], [right]]
```

from starting range:

```
        |-----
 row 1  |  5
        |-----
 row 2  |
 row 3  |  3
 row 4  |
        |-----
 row 5  |
        |-----
 row 6  |  1
        |-----
```

"general" aligned cells will give you the answer where merged range is.

Comment: I like this thank you. It doesn't rely on someone changing the color of the cells