# Paste Range WITH merge but WITHOUT conditional formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm stuck! Am I missing a function or object or is there a reasonable workaround?

**I'd like to copy a range from one sheet to another sheet within the same Google Spreadsheet, copying the merged state of the cells but *not* copying the Conditional Formatting rules.**

As far as I can tell: the only way to copy the merged state is to include formatting in the paste (i.e. a full paste), which *also* pastes the conditional formatting rules. There is no programmatic way to interact with the conditional formatting rules at all, nor is there a way to get merged state without complex workarounds.

Is there a way to do it?

If not, I could replace the conditional formatting with an onEdit(e) to evaluate each cell after edit if the edit occurred within a specified range (but that's proving a pain) then do the full paste.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, can you apply

```
.clearFormat()
```

to your pasted range, followed by

```
.merge()
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge

Comment: Thanks; that could remove conditional formatting and selectively merge cells but requires the entire source range to be evaluated for merged cells through complex workarounds like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025543/how-do-i-know-if-spreadsheet-cells-are-merged-using-google-apps-script) and then used to apply the merges in a loop. Since there's a paste mode for ONLY conditional formatting, I was hoping there was one (or a simple approach) to paste everything BUT conditional formatting.